# SoundPool running out of memory?

Tags: android

I have the following class.

```
class SoundLoadManager(val ctx:Context) {
    var scheduled = 0
    var loaded = 0
    val sndPool: SoundPool
    val soundPoolMap = mutableMapOf<Int,Int>()
    init {
        sndPool =
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=
                        Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    SoundPool.Builder()
                            .setMaxStreams(10)
                            .setAudioAttributes(
                                    AudioAttributes.Builder()
                                            .setUsage(
                                                    AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
                                            .setContentType(
                                                    AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                                            .build()
                            ).build()
                } else {
                    SoundPool(10,
                            AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                            100)
                }
        sndPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener({
            sndPool, sampleId, status ->
            if(status != 0) {
                Log.e("LOG",
                        "Sound could not be loaded")
            } else {
                Log.i("LOG", "Loaded sample " +
                        sampleId + ", status = " +
                        status)
            }
            loaded++
        })
    }
    fun load(resourceId:Int) {
        scheduled++
        soundPoolMap[resourceId] =
                sndPool.load(ctx, resourceId, 1)
    }
    fun allLoaded() = scheduled == loaded
    fun play(rsrcId: Int, loop: Boolean):Int {
        return soundPoolMap[rsrcId]?.run {
            val audioManager = ctx.getSystemService(
                    Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
            val curVolume = audioManager.
                    getStreamVolume(
                            AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
            val maxVolume = audioManager.
                    getStreamMaxVolume(
                            AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
            val leftVolume = 1f * curVolume / maxVolume
            val rightVolume = 1f * curVolume / maxVolume
            val priority = 1
            val noLoop = if(loop) -1 else 0
            val normalPlaybackRate = 1f
            sndPool.play(this, leftVolume, rightVolume,
                    priority, noLoop, normalPlaybackRate)
        } ?: -1
    }
}
```

And am utilizing it as follows.

```
fun playHarmonicInterval(baseInterval: String, scaleDegree: String? ){



           soundLoadManager.load(getResources().getIdentifier(baseInterval, "raw", getPackageName()));
           soundLoadManager.load(getResources().getIdentifier(scaleDegree, "raw", getPackageName()))
            // more ...

        timer = Timer()
        timer.schedule(object : TimerTask() {
            override fun run() {
                if(soundLoadManager.allLoaded()){
                    soundLoadManager.play(getResources().getIdentifier(baseInterval, "raw", getPackageName()), false)
                    soundLoadManager.play(getResources().getIdentifier(scaleDegree, "raw", getPackageName()), false)
                    timer.cancel();

                }
            }
        }, 0, 100)


    }
```

My question is do I need to worry about my SoundLoadManager eating up alot of memory doing it this way and causing the app to crash. Or because it is creating sounds inside a function I don't need to worry about it?

After the response below I have updated my code to the following. It seems to still work OK.

```
fun playHarmonicInterval(baseInterval: String, scaleDegree: String? ){

        soundLoadManager = SoundLoadManager(this)


         var  value1 = soundLoadManager.load(getResources().getIdentifier(baseInterval, "raw", getPackageName()));
         var value2 =  soundLoadManager.load(getResources().getIdentifier(scaleDegree, "raw", getPackageName()))


        timer = Timer()
        timer.schedule(object : TimerTask() {
            override fun run() {
                if(soundLoadManager.allLoaded()){
                    soundLoadManager.play(getResources().getIdentifier(baseInterval, "raw", getPackageName()), false)
                    soundLoadManager.play(getResources().getIdentifier(scaleDegree, "raw", getPackageName()), false)
                    timer.cancel();
                    soundLoadManager.sndPool?.release()
                    soundLoadManager.sndPool = null;

                }
            }
        }, 0, 100)


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you will run out of memory eventually, assuming you load enough unique sounds. `SoundPool` is storing the sounds it loads in uncompressed form. And, it must keep them in this state, because a `play()` request could come in at any moment (as far as it knows).  `SoundPool` will not free sounds without an explicit call to [`release()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html#release()) or [`unload()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html#unload(int)).

Then again, if you don't have a lot of sounds, then you will probably not run out of memory, because short sound clips are relatively small.

Also note that, if you pass the same resource ID to `SoundLoadManager.load()` twice, your code will overwrite an exising sound ID (`soundPoolMap`), meaning you can never call `unload()` for that particular sound. Maybe `SoundPool` is smart enough not to load the sound twice, and it just returns the original sound ID; I don't know. I'd have to test it.

So, it is possible that you could eventually run out of memory, even if you only have a small number of sound files, if they are played repeatedly (because you are never calling `unload()`).

> Or because it is creating sounds inside a function I don't need to worry about it?

Incorrect! These are not local variables. Your sounds have a larger scope than that, by virtue of the `SoundPool` object; the function has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Actually, you can load many samples if they are short in size. This is what SoundPool is about. For longer files use MediaPlayer class where you don't need to load the whole track into memory.

Comment: @greeble31 thanks. Could you guide me on how to properly unload each sound right after it plays? I think an unload method on the class would work. But I am not sure how to unload and remove from sound pool map. Also only have total around 50 small .wav files that are being repeatedly used. Probably biggest is 400kb.

Comment: I just looked the largest .wav file is 200kb and there are 50 total. For all 50 the size on disk is 9.5 MB. Would it be better to just call release every time?

Comment: I am releasing the soundPool and setting it to null after it plays the sound. Please see my updated code and let me know if this is a good solution. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @james Generally, for a modern mobile device, 9.5MB isn't a crazy amount of RAM. In your case, it looks like you can tolerate a `release()` after each play, and your current solution is obviously vastly superior in terms of memory efficiency. However: The chief advantage of SoundPool is the ability to load many sounds during app initialization, then play them at will. Since you're willing to tolerate the "loading" delay at the moment of "play", then you may find MediaPlayer much more straightforward and easy to use. It'll also help you avoid the ugliness of timer-polling `allLoaded`.